# My goal here is to have the user choose between 3 options and if they don't it shows an error message and keeps them in the loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

The top 3 lines just generates 3 random pokemon names. The issue comes in the "If" statement as when the user inputs something that is not an option, it passes the if statement, but because it wasn't an option, the user is still stuck in the while loop.

```
def pkmn_choice1():
    Pokemon1 = Pokemon_dct[f'{random_pkmn1}'].pokechoice()
    Pokemon2 = Pokemon_dct[f'{random_pkmn2}'].pokechoice()
    Pokemon3 = Pokemon_dct[f'{random_pkmn3}'].pokechoice()
    choices1 = [f'{Pokemon1}', f'{Pokemon2}', f'{Pokemon3}']
    print("Choose one of these Pokemon to fight with.")
    userinput1 = ""
    while userinput1 not in choices1:
        print(f"Options: {Pokemon1}, {Pokemon2}, or {Pokemon3}.")
        userinput1 = input()
        if userinput1 == f"{Pokemon1}" or f"{Pokemon2}" or f"{Pokemon3}":
            print(f'You have chosen {userinput1} to be your partner.')
            Pokemon_dct[f'{userinput1}'].pokeinfo1()
        else:
            print("That was not a valid selection. Please try again")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al. You want something like `if userinput1 in (f"{Pokemon1}", f"{Pokemon2}", f"{Pokemon3}"):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you build proper comparison against multiple values. Instead of:

```
if userinput1 == f"{Pokemon1}" or f"{Pokemon2}" or f"{Pokemon3}":
```

you need to write

```
if userinput1 == f"{Pokemon1}" or userinput1 == f"{Pokemon2}" or userinput1 == f"{Pokemon3}":
```

but that gets lengthy so go smarter and write

```
if userinput1 in [f"{Pokemon1}", f"{Pokemon2}", f"{Pokemon3}"]:
```